# Angular Material Select Dropdown, Emit Whole Object Item, not just a value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7, angular8

Angular Material select dropdown API only emits a value. Both `[(ngModel)]` and `(selectionChange)` only emit single member , not the whole object data field.

For example eg, it only emits the food.value = 2,  does not emit other class fields for a row list item, like foodName, foodDescription, foodWeight, etc, (need to emit all the corresponding members for a listId)

How do I emit the whole object for food, given an food.value ?  Needs to work for Any Material Dropdown in the future created, not just specific cases. Does Material Angular have any specific options to allow this?

The answers below, only work for one particular example, trying to see larger picture.

https://material.angular.io/components/select/api

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Class example, for 2, need foodCategory, Calories, and other fields, etc

```
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [
    {value: '0', viewValue: 'Steak', foodCategory: 'Meat', Calories: 50},
    {value: '1', viewValue: 'Pizza', foodCategory: 'Carbs', Calories: 100},
    {value: '2', viewValue: 'Apple', foodCategory: 'Fruit', Calories: 25}
  ];
}
```

**Does anyone have a better solution?**
Otherwise, will to write this in the `selectionChange` onOutput method. Seems like Angular Materials would have better option,

```
this.foods.find(x=>x.value =="2")
```

Note for solutions below; Need to have solution for any different classes, with many type of members, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable }    from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  titleAlert: string = 'This field is required';
  selected;
  data = [
    {value: '0', viewValue: 'Steak', foodCategory: 'Meat', Calories: 50},
    {value: '1', viewValue: 'Pizza', foodCategory: 'Carbs', Calories: 100},
    {value: '2', viewValue: 'Apple', foodCategory: 'Fruit', Calories: 25}
  ];;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selected = 0
  }


}
```

```html
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of data; let i = index" [value]="i">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<div>
Selected value: {{data[selected].foodCategory}}
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to work in snippet or on my computer, do you have a stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-angular-material-reactive-form-krifxf?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Has your problem been resolved? @Artportraitdesign1

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods; let i = index" [value]="i" (onSelectionChange)="onValueChange(food)">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: what is onValueChange?

Comment: onValueChange is just a function name.. U can write any function in your ts file and call it in onSelectionChange.

Answer (score 1):

## How to emit the whole object in a Material `Select` Component

The `Select` component from the Angular Material library does emit the whole object. Anything you define in the `value` in the `mat-option` input directive will be emitted when you the select the correspondent value. This is the usual way how it behave.

As side note: Be careful with the used brackets `[]` as they define that the set value is an object and not a string.

**Don't use it like that**

<strike>`<mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>`</strike>

**Instead**

`<mat-option [value]="someObject">Option 3</mat-option>`

1. Set the object as value to the mat-option components

   See how the value is set using the `row` object of the `data` array

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Select a food option</mat-label>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="handleSelect($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let row of data" [value]="row">{{ row.name }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

2. Define a method for the event emitter

```
  handleSelect(food: any) {
    // Here is the actual selected object
    console.log(food.value);
    this.selected = JSON.stringify(food.value);
  }
```

For your reference: https://stackblitz.com/angular/annvxmlqlqe

Comment: the example you gave only uses a single object, I need example with multi member dto

Comment: I need to find a way to emit the whole object all the multiple Members within the class,  this is a single select dropdown

Comment: For multiple objects you can add the `multiple` directive:
<mat-select multiple>

Comment: no, Multiple members within the single selection, please refer to question

Comment: What are multiple members within the single selection?

Comment: my class has multiple property members, food name, type description, etc

Comment: In your example, please provide the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Your onSelectionChange($event) function can emit any object, it is not tightly coupled with the data structure you want to display. I had a similar problem with a list of locations, I modified your solution a bit:

Template:

```
<form formGroup="foodForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControl]="foodControl">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
// Food list may come from anywhere, even from inside the controller, or from 
  an API
foods: Food[] = [
  {value: '0', viewValue: 'Steak', foodCategory: 'Meat', Calories: 50},
  {value: '1', viewValue: 'Pizza', foodCategory: 'Carbs', Calories: 100},
  {value: '2', viewValue: 'Apple', foodCategory: 'Fruit', Calories: 25}
];
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  @Output() foodSelectionChange = new EventEmitter<any>();
  // if food comes from a parent component @Input() foods;

  foodForm: FormGroup;
  foodControl = new FormControl();

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.foodForm = fb.group({
      food: this.locationControl
    });
  }

  onFoodSelectionChange(event): void {
    const food = this.foods.find(element => element.value === event.value);
    this.foodSelectionChange.emit(food);
  }
}
```

You can set the default value of your formControl in the OnInit lifecycle:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.foodForm.controls['food'].setValue(/any value/);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let food of data; let i = index" [value]="i">
          {{food.viewValue}}
       </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
Selected value: {{data[selected].foodCategory}}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thvpvz

Answer (score 0):

Here is a selection that returns the object

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
// import { Observable }    from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  selected = "";
  data = [
    { value: "0", viewValue: "Steak", foodCategory: "Meat", Calories: 50 },
    { value: "1", viewValue: "Pizza", foodCategory: "Carbs", Calories: 100 },
    { value: "2", viewValue: "Apple", foodCategory: "Fruit", Calories: 25 }
  ];
}
```

```html
<h2>Select Food</h2>
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
  <mat-option value="">Select favorite food</mat-option>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of data" [value]="food">
   {{food.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<div>
 <p>Your Favorite food is</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Food Name: {{selected.viewValue}}</li>
    <li>Calories: {{selected.Calories}}</li>
    <li>Category: {{selected.foodCategory}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Look it up at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4oivc

Comment: this only displays all the values, what if I have 50 member?

Comment: Your initial question was "How do I emit the whole object for food..?"

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution without using indexes or searching through the collection.
The issue is that the select component doesn't know how to compare two objects.
The [component API](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) allows to set a `compareWith` function to accomplish this.

Example:

My component gets a Set/Array of DTOs passed to it:

```
<app-user-select [(selectedUsers)]="dock.authorizedUsers"></app-user-select>
```

The template is a simple select, but with `compareWith` set:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Users</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selectedUsers" (valueChange)="selectedUsersChange.emit(selectedUsers)" [compareWith]="deepCompare" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of availableUsers" [value]="user">{{user.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In the controller I define what the object equality is in the `deepCompare` function. Equality in my model is the equality of the two fields `identitySourceId` and `id`:

```
export class UserSelectComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  selectedUsers: Set<UserDto> = new Set<UserDto>();
  @Output()
  selectedUsersChange = new EventEmitter<Set<UserDto>>();

  availableUsers: Array<UserDto>;

  constructor(private userApiService: UserApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAvailableUsers();
  }

  private getAvailableUsers() {
    this.userApiService.getUsers().subscribe({
      next: users => this.availableUsers = users
    })
  }

  public deepCompare(optionValue: UserDto, selectionValue: UserDto): boolean {
    return optionValue.identitySourceId == selectionValue.identitySourceId && optionValue.id == selectionValue.id;
  }

}
```

The `compareWith` function can of course do a deep equality check too.

This code loads the collection properly into the selected values and also emits the full collection to the parent.